# bash associative key with a Variable key

Tags: bash

Im trying to create an array and then get the value of a key using the following commands:

```
declare -A email_addresses
mail_address=(["dev"]="dev.com" ["sandbox"]="sandbox.com")
env=$(#command to get env) # result is "sandbox"
echo ${email_address[$env]}
```

However it keeps throwing this error at me : `-bash: "hsandbox": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""sandbox"")`

Im not sure how to get past this. If I do `echo $env` it returns `"sandbox"` and not `""sandbox""` so Im not sure what seems to be the issue.

Comment: If `echo "$env"` contains quotes in the output at all, that means you have **literal** quotes in your string's data. Those aren't desirable -- in `mail_address=( ["sandbox"]="sandbox.com" )`, all the quotes are **syntactic**, not literal.

Comment: If your "command to get env" is using `jq`, for instance, use the `-r` option -- for raw output -- to avoid quote literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your "command to get env" to not be emitting literal quotes in its output. Barring that:

```
# strip leading and trailing quotes from env
env=${env%'"'}; env=${env#'"'}

echo "${email_address[$env]}"
```

---

#### Python-Audience-Friendly Explanation

To explain this in a manner that makes sense to folks who know Python (since that's where most of the OP's rep comes from):

**`echo "$foo"` in shell behaves like the Python command `print str(foo)`, not the Python command `print repr(foo)`.**

Consider the following REPL session:

```
>>> mail_address = { "dev": "dev.com", "sandbox": "sandbox.com" }
>>> env = getSomething()
>>> print str(env)
"dev"
>>> print mail_address[env]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"dev"'
>>> print repr(env)
'"dev"'
```

You've got the exact same problem: Your dictionary contains `dev` as its literal contents, but your key's literal contents are `"dev"`.

---

#### Avoiding Confusion In The Future: Unambiguously Printing Shell Variables

If you want to print a variable's contents in shell in a way that's unambiguous (in the same respect in which `print repr(env)` is unambiguous in Python), `echo` is the wrong tool for the job. Consider instead one of the following:

```
$ declare -p env           ## caveat: doesn't work for all non-printable characters
declare -- env="\"dev\""
$ printf 'env=%q\n' "$env" ## caveat: doesn't work for non-string datatypes
env=\"dev\"
```

---

#### An Aside: Why You Should Always Quote Arguments To `echo` (Or Not Use It)

While it looks innocuous, the code

```
echo $foo
```

actually has surprisingly complicated behavior. Consider the following:

```
foo=$'\thello\tworld\t*\n\\text'
```

That's the bash equivalent to the following Python:

```
foo='\thello\tworld\t*\n\\text'
```

Now, let's see what happens if you actually use `echo` to print it with `echo $foo`, if you have a default value for `IFS` and your shell is bash:

- The first tab disappears altogether
- The other tabs are replaced by spaces
- The newline literal is replaced by a space
- The `*` is replaced by a list of files in the current directory.

That is to say, the behavior in bash of `echo $foo` is equivalent to the following Python:

```
import itertools, glob
foo='\thello\tworld\t*\n\\text'
print ' '.join(itertools.chain(*[ glob.glob(s) for s in foo.split() ]))
```

By contrast, consider:

```
echo "$foo"
```

In that case, you'll get the expected behavior... in bash.

Why "in bash"? Because the [POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) *doesn't specify* behavior when any backslash literal is included in the text. `echo` could do literally anything in this circumstance and still be POSIX-compliant, and BSD-style implementations will behave differently than XSI-style ones do.

Comment: Your comment about using the `-r` for `jq` actually solved it.

Comment: Heh. Question didn't specify that you were using `jq`, so that was very much a guess, as opposed to something supported by the text. :)

Comment: Yeah my bad. the command is a long aws one and it dint seem relevant. completely forgot about the jq bit I had at the end

Comment: BTW, I've amended in an aside on the behavior of `echo $foo` in shell, which tends to be... surprising.